# Установить более-менее свежий firefox на debian 5.0

Tags: debian, firefox

Добрый день.

Может кто-нибудь встречал сборку firefox версии 30+, которая-бы без проблем встала на старый debian lenny? Сборка с mozilla.org вылетает с ошибкой:

```
$ /opt/firefox/firefox
/opt/firefox/firefox: symbol lookup error: /opt/firefox/libxul.so: undefined symbol: gtk_widget_set_can_focus
```

Обновлять из-за браузера всю систему не хочется совершенно - эта машина работает как терминальный сервер (NX, wine+1C, wine+Консультант и прочее).

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

возможно, ошибка появляется из-за того, что версии `xulrunner` и/или `libgtk2.0-0`, установленные в системе, слишком стары.

более новую сборку этих пакетов можно (вместе с необходимыми зависимостями) установить из репозитория `lenny-backports`.

подключить его можно, добавив в `/etc/apt/sources.list` строку вида:

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-backports lenny-backports main contrib non-free
```

но при выполнении `aptitude update`, вероятно, появится ошибка вида:

```
E: Release file for http://archive.debian.org/debian-backports/dists/lenny-backports/Release is expired (invalid since 1124d 0h 2min 28s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
```

в этом случае надо добавить при вызове `aptitude update` опцию игнорирования валидности даты файла `Release`:

```
aptitude -o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false update
```

а затем установить пакеты (и необходимые зависимости) из подключенного репозитория:

```
aptitude -t lenny-backports install xulrunner libgtk2.0-0
```

p.s. возможно, потребуется обновить и другие записи в `/etc/apt/sources.list`, если они не обновлялись с момента завершения жизненного цикла версии `lenny`.

например, если в качестве зеркала использовался `mirror.yandex.ru`, то записи выглядят примерно так:

```
deb http://mirror.yandex.ru/debian ...
```

вот `mirror.yandex.ru` и надо заменить на `archive.debian.org`:

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian ...
```

Comment: Ваш ответ очень подробный и верный, но, к сожалению, для меня совершенно не подходит. На этой машине уже стоит xulrunner-1.9.1 из lenny-backports - и эта версия не позволяет запустить firefox v30.0+.
Тем не менее - спасибо.

Comment: а пакет `libgtk2.0-0` какой версии стоит? в `lenny-backports` есть версии `2.18.6`. если у вас ниже, попробуйте установить его из этого репозитория.

Comment: О! Вот это помогло! Большое спасибо!

Comment: дополнил ответ упоминанием libgtk2.0-0.